# How to create array of latitude given latitude as a function of coordinates x and y?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset `df`
[image]
Lat and Lon are a function of coordinates x (shape=(349,)) and y (shape = (277,)). I want to create an array of latitude values for each grid point (i.e. I want an array that has the shape= (96673,)). I'm using the following loop:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4 as nc

lats=[]
lons=[]
for x in df.x:
    for y in df.y:
        latitude=df.sel(x = x, y = y).lat.values
        lats.append(latitude)
```

but when I do this I get a list of arrays that is the correct length (96673), but is unusable because of the format. It looks like this:
[image]

How can I use the loop above or something similar and get an array?

Comment: What version of python and numpy are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and the latest numpy, but x and y are xarray data arrays which I suspect is where the problem is. Is there a way to do something similar to this without xarray?

Comment: In your post it looks like `lats` is not empty, could you check this again? Maybe instead of doing `lats.append(latitude)` try lats.append(latitude[0]) if the arrays are all of length 1 that might work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each array in `latitude`  has only one item each time, you can use [`xarray.DataArray.item`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.item.html)

```py
lats=[]
lons=[]
for x in df.x:
    for y in df.y:
        latitude=df.sel(x = x, y = y).lat.values
        lats.append(latitude.item(0))
```

Comment: when I do that I get the following message: 

ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate

Comment: @MeganMartin Did you add `np.concatenate(lats)` after your code and then rerun all the cells? From your image I expected `lats` to be a list filled with numpy arrays, is that right?

Comment: I ran the same code that I showed above and then added "only_lats = np.concatenate(lats)" after the loop, outside of the loop and got that error message. It looks like lats is a list filled with numpy arrays

Comment: the arrays in your list could be of type `<xarray.DataArray ()>array()` that supports `item` to get the values, could you try using `lats.append(latitude.item(0))` (assuming only 1 value per array) and i will change my answer

Comment: Could you mark the question as resolved

Comment: I think this would work best if you don't provide any arguments to item - that is, `lats.append(latitude.item())`. This will ensure that the list is full of python scalars.